# Proof that $\mathbf{X}_n - \mathbf{X} =o_p(2)$ iff $||\mathbf{X}_n - \mathbf{X}||=o_p(1)$

Tags: probability, asymptotics

In the following proof of the proposition, I do not understand the very first statement where it says "for every $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|X_n^j - X^j|^2 > \epsilon/k) = 0$ for $j= 1, \cdots, k$." From the definition of $o_p(1)$, shouldn't it be: for every $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}P(|X_n^j - X^j| > \epsilon/k) = 0$ for $j= 1, \cdots, k$, so where did the squared come from?

[image]

Comment: It seems to be a device to facilitate that proof. The author mentions Proposition 3.4; check that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n^j-X^j|^2 > \epsilon/k) = \mathbb{P}(|X_n^j-X^j| > \sqrt{\epsilon/k}).$$

As $X_n-X = o_p(1)$, the right-hand side converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.